# Condition AND OR with Drupal db_select

Tags: sql, drupal-7, conditional-statements, where-clause

Hi how can i do a condition like that in drupal  ?

```
WHERE (date = xxx and time = xxx) OR (date = xxx and time = xxx)
```

I want to do this condition with db_select.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thx for fast answer, i just found it.

here is my solution :

```
$and_1 = db_and()->condition('b.date' , $date, '=')->condition('b.time', $begin_time, '>');
$and_2 = db_and()->condition('b.date' , $tomorrow, '=')->condition('b.time', '00:00', '>=')

$query->condition(db_or()->condition($and_1)->condition($and_2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$query = db_select('yourtable', 't');
$query->condition(db_or()->condition(db_and()->condition('t.date', xxx, '=')->condition('t.time', xxx, '='))
                         ->condition(db_and()->condition('t.date', xxx, '=')->condition('t.time', xxx, '=')));
```

Comment: That isn't right...produces `SELECT  
FROM 
{yourtable} t
WHERE  (t.date = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (t.time = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND( (t.date = :db_condition_placeholder_2) OR (t.time = :db_condition_placeholder_3) )`